# How to display temp array data to client

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii, append, yii1.x

My form will submit data and get a result on the same page to the user for only viewing. The result will not save any where.
my image form is 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFFKT.png)

As above image select 2 parameter which save on Db and 1 length which is temp .

On select length after submit.
On submit below table will show result in table as type ,volatage .,resultR,resultX,resultB to user.

length,resultR=length*r,resultX=length*x,resultB=length*b all  three are temp array.
user can do many time for result and shown row by row and on clear click all result will erase.

Comment: its like use javascript append and prepend for dynamic but dont know how.Any one can send code for that

Comment: So you want to show the data for some amount of time??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one way to do it is to keep a `div` which acts as a container for all the results in the second table. You can the save the result you got from the submit and append that data to the second tables `div`.Something like this:

```
$("#second-table-div table").append('<tr><td>resultR : '+somevalue+'</td><td>...</td></tr>');
```

Once the user clicks 'clear' button, you can simply write a small jquery or javascript, something like this:

```
$('#clear').on('click',function(){
  $("#second-table-div").html('');
});
```

Comment: thanks but you have any demo this type because i m new in yii .If you have then send it

Comment: Actually its not related to yii, you can achieve it using pure javascript or jquery. I dont have any demo, but if you can provide a sample code of what you did, I might be able to change that.

Comment: i want simple as take value from form as length and r value from type table then result=r * length .In below it show but not save in db.i dont know how to do

Comment: ya its totally javascript only

Comment: You dont need to save it in the db, once you submit, you can access the data(methods available online). Do the calculations of the values and create DOM table using jquery/js (methods available online), then you use the above solution to append the data to second table.